# Checking for nulls inside object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

So I want to display these rows from my database as a table, not all columns are filled, some rows have a null for column3 or columnX.

```
if(datos[i].column1== "" || datos[i].column1== null)
                        datos[i].column1= "-";
                    if(datos[i].column2== "" || datos[i].column2== null)
                        datos[i].column2= "-";
                    if(datos[i].column3== "" || datos[i].column3== null)
                        datos[i].column3= "-";
                    if(datos[i].column4 == "" || datos[i].column4 == null)
                        datos[i].column4 = "-";
                    if(datos[i].column5 == "" || datos[i].column5== null)
                        datos[i].column5 = "-";
                    if(datos[i].column6 == "" || datos[i].column6 == null)
                        datos[i].column6 = "-";
                    if(datos[i].column7 == "" || datos[i].column7== null)
                        datos[i].column7= "-";
                    s+='<tr>'+
                       ' <td data-type="1">'+ datos[i].column1 + '</td>' +
                       ' <td data-type="2">'+ datos[i].column2 + '</td>' +
                       ' <td data-type="3">'+ datos[i].column3 + '</td>' +
                       ' <td data-type="4">'+ datos[i].column4 + '</td>' +
                       ' <td data-type="5">'+ datos[i].column5 + '</td>' +
                       ' <td data-type="6">'+ datos[i].column6.substr(0, 10) + '</td>' +
                       ' <td data-type="7">'+ datos[i].column7.substr(0, 10) + '</td>' +
                       ' <td data-type="8">'+ datos[i].column8.substr(0, 10) + '</td>' +
                       ' <td data-type="9">'+ datos[i].column9+ '</td>' +
                       ' <td data-type="10">'+ datos[i].column10+ '</td>' +
                       ' <td data-align="center"><p data-placement="top"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick=LlenaDatos("' + datos[i].column2+ '")><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></p></td> ' +
                       '</tr>';
```

I think it looks very savage-like, I was hoping for a less primitive way to check all columns for nulls or empty and have them appear as just a dash.

Comment: So, your code works but you'd like to improve it? If this is the case, maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for it.

Comment: I didn't know about that :O Well now I'll know for future questions such as this and yes, the code work, I just didn't know how to loop it to not have to write blocks like the one I did. Thank you all~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
s += '<tr>';
$.each(datos[i], function(key, val){
   if(!val)
      datos[i][key] = "-";
   s += ' <td data-type="1">'+ datos[i][key] + '</td>';
});
s += '<td data-align="center"><p data-placement="top"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick=LlenaDatos("' + datos[i].column2+ '")><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></p></td></tr>';
```

Now you can do everything in one single loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the data, you could use an `||` operator to return something else if the string is null or empty.

```
...
' <td data-type="1">'+ (datos[i].column1 || '-') + '</td>' +
' <td data-type="2">'+ (datos[i].column2 || '-') + '</td>' +
...
```